# i don't understand this lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, functional-programming, boolean

i looked on the web for a lambda that one could use to get prime numbers. i found this:

```
nums = range(2, 100)
for i in range(2, 10):
    nums = list(filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, nums))
print(nums)
```

i understand how `x % i` —being `i` a list of numbers from 2 to 10— can filter out the non-prime numbers that are higher then 10; what boggles my mind is how would one add the `i` list to the final `nums`.

i believe it may have something to do with the `x == i` boolean but i can't understand how it works.

Comment: note, it's not `x == 1`, but `x == i` (i.e. not **one**, but **i**)

Comment: you are correct

Comment: (x equals to i) or (x modules i) -- if either of these result positive number, final nums list will contain those values ... list of i's will not end up to the nums list, its used to test the values in initial nums.

Comment: ¿wouldn't `x == i` add each number from `range(2, 10)` to `nums`?

Comment: yes, but because you overwrite nums on each iteration for the for loop, the those values are already gone when x == i ..

Comment: No *adding* to `nums` is being done in the loop: only selective *removal* of the non-prime numbers.

Comment: You could try adding `print(nums)` on each iteration of the loop, so you can see step-by-step how the non-primes are progressively removed.

Comment: @slothrop Exactly .. nums is updated and if any of the for loop from I - returns False, number from nums is removed on per loop .. even  in case where some of the iterations  could evalute to True. Answer was for was for op's question "wouldn't x == i" add every number to the nums ..

Comment: @rasjani Very true, the fact that the loop goes in ascending order of i is important, so that the non-prime values are already gone when x == i, just as you say.

Comment: ¡thanks for the help! by adding `print(nums)` to the for loop i understood how in the first loop most non-prime numbers are removed.  then, with 4 and 6 —removed with the `i % 2`— the `i == x` no longer aplies, as @rasjani said.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda-Functions can be used to shorten code. They can be compared to "normal" functions which use at least two lines of code.
func will be the same as your lambda-function:

```
def func(x):
    return x == i or x % i
```

Driver Code:

```
nums = range(2, 100)
nums_a = []
for i in range(2, 10):
    nums = list(filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, nums))
    nums_a = list(filter(func, nums))

print(nums_a)
print(nums)
```

Comment: yes, my question would be how does `x == i` in both functions add the prime numbers that are lower than 10 to `nums`. i guess it could be described more specifically as a question about how `filter()` works in this case.

Comment: Note that in the first line, `nums` is initialised to `range(2, 100)`.  The rest of the code doesn't work by *adding prime numbers* to `nums`, but rather by *removing non-prime numbers* from `nums`.  Now, think about the loop iteration where `i=5` (just as an example).  We want to remove 10, 15, 20 etc - those are multiples of 5 so they can't be prime.  By requiring `x%5` to be nonzero, we exclude all those multiples of 5.  But that would also remove 5 itself!  So we add the `x == i` term to ensure that the filter does not remove the prime number 5.

Comment: that is what i don't understand, ¿why are the non-prime numbers from `range(2, 10)` removed?

Comment: Consider the iteration of the loop where `i = 3` for example.  Now consider how the value `x = 6` behaves in the filter.  `6 == 3` is false, and `6 % 3` is 0 (which behaves as false).  So the filter function is false for `x = 6`, and hence 6 is removed from `nums`.  (That's just an example, the same goes for all the other non-primes.)

Answer (score 0):

This lambda function wants to check if a number is equal to a number between 2 and 9 and is not divisible by any one of them.

In other words, the whole program what to filter the prime numbers here the list is from 2 to 99 the in the loop. we just need to check the divisors from 2 to 9 because If we pass to 10 we could find `10 * 10 = 100`.